# Height of View not being calculated when paddingVertical is used in a React Native View

Tags: react-native

This is my render method

```
  render() {
    return (<View style={{
      display: "flex",
      backgroundColor: "green",
      paddingVertical: 20
    }}>
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: "red", flex: 1, position: "absolute", height: "100%", width: "100%" }} />
      <Text>This is the text</Text>
      <Text>This is the text</Text>
      <Text>This is the text</Text>
      <Text>This is the text</Text>
    </View>)
  }
```

The output is as follows:

[image]
I was expecting the red View to completely overlap the parent green View. Works well if the Parent does not have a paddingVertical defined. Any way to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**On `Red View component`**

Change `height: 100% and width: 100%` to `top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0 and right: 0`

```jsx
return (
  <View
    style={{
      display: "flex",
      backgroundColor: "green",
      paddingVertical: 20
    }}
  >
    <View
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "red",
        flex: 1,
        position: "absolute",
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0
      }}
    />
    <Text>This is the text</Text>
    <Text>This is the text</Text>
    <Text>This is the text</Text>
    <Text>This is the text</Text>
  </View>
);
```